# How to Run an Async Action Creator inside an Async Redux Thunk Action Creator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to figure out the correct implementation of running an Async Action Creator inside an Async Redux Thunk Action Creator. Which of the following is the correct method?

**Method 1:**

```
export const loginUser = () => async(dispatch) => {        
    try {
        user = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);                              
        dispatch({type: LOGIN, payload: user});
        dispatch({type:SAVE_USER_TO_DEVICE, payload:saveUserToDevice(user)});                              
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const saveUserToDevice = async(user)=> {        
    try {
        //saveUserToDeviceStatus returns true if successful, otherwise returns an object
        const saveUserToDeviceStatus = await Keychain.setGenericPassword('user', JSON.stringify(user)); 
        return (saveUserToDeviceStatus? true: false);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }    
}
```

**Method 2:** saveUserToDevice dispatch itself

```
export const loginUser = () => async(dispatch) => {        
    try {                     
        user = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);                      
        dispatch({type: LOGIN, payload: user});
        saveUserToDevice(user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const saveUserToDevice = (user) => async(dispatch) => {        
    try {
        //saveUserToDeviceStatus returns true if successful, otherwise returns an object
        const saveUserToDeviceStatus = await Keychain.setGenericPassword('user', JSON.stringify(user)); 
        saveUserToDeviceStatus = saveUserToDeviceStatus? true: false;
        dispatch({type: SAVE_USER_TO_DEVICE, payload: saveUserToDeviceStatus});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }    
}
```

**Method 3:** saveUserToDevice returns action object

```
export const loginUser = () => async(dispatch) => {        
    try {                     
        user = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);                      
        dispatch({type: LOGIN, payload: user});
        const saveUserToDeviceAction = await saveUserToDevice(user);
        dispatch(saveUserToDeviceAction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const saveUserToDevice = async(user) => {        
    try {
        //saveUserToDeviceStatus returns true if successful, otherwise returns an object
        const saveUserToDeviceStatus = await Keychain.setGenericPassword('user', JSON.stringify(user)); 
        saveUserToDeviceStatus = saveUserToDeviceStatus? true: false;
       return {type: SAVE_USER_TO_DEVICE, payload: saveUserToDeviceStatus};
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }    
}
```

**Method 4:** saveUserToDevice returns boolean, dispatch is triggered inside loginUser

```
export const loginUser = () => async(dispatch) => {        
    try {                     
        user = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);                      
        dispatch({type: LOGIN, payload: user});
        const saveUserToDeviceAction = await saveUserToDevice(user);
        dispatch({type: SAVE_USER_TO_DEVICE, payload: saveUserToDeviceAction});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const saveUserToDevice = async(user) => {        
    try {
        //saveUserToDeviceStatus returns true if successful, otherwise returns an object
        const saveUserToDeviceStatus = await Keychain.setGenericPassword('user', JSON.stringify(user)); 
        saveUserToDeviceStatus = saveUserToDeviceStatus? true: false;
       return saveUserToDeviceStatus;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saveUserToDevice` is an action and you need to actually `dispatch` the action and not just call it.

The correct way would be

```
dispatch(saveUserToDevice(user));
```

Also `saveUserToDevice` must dispatch the action as

```
dispatch({type: SAVE_USER_TO_DEVICE, payload: saveUserToDeviceStatus});
```

Full Code

```
export const loginUser = () => async(dispatch) => {        
    try {                     
        user = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);                      
        dispatch({type: LOGIN, payload: user});
        dispatch(saveUserToDevice(user));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const saveUserToDevice = (user) => async(dispatch) => {        
    try {
        //saveUserToDeviceStatus returns true if successful, otherwise returns an object
        const saveUserToDeviceStatus = await Keychain.setGenericPassword('user', JSON.stringify(user)); 
        saveUserToDeviceStatus = saveUserToDeviceStatus? true: false;
        dispatch({type: SAVE_USER_TO_DEVICE, payload: saveUserToDeviceStatus});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }    
}
```

As per your first solution is concerned if would work if you wait on `saveUserToDevice(result)}` like

```
export const loginUser = () => async(dispatch) => {        
    try {
        user = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);                              
        dispatch({type: LOGIN, payload: user});
        const data = await saveUserToDevice(result);
        dispatch({type:SAVE_USER_TO_DEVICE, payload: data});                              
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export const saveUserToDevice = async(user)=> {        
    try {
        //saveUserToDeviceStatus returns true if successful, otherwise returns an object
        const saveUserToDeviceStatus = await Keychain.setGenericPassword('user', JSON.stringify(user)); 
        return (saveUserToDeviceStatus? true: false);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }    
}
```

However of the two approaches, its cleaner to go with the approach of making `saveUserToDevice` being an action and dispatch it

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite understand. In method 2, there is a dispatch inside saveUserToDevice() . 
Should I use loginUser() as thunk action creator and saveUserToDevice() as normal action creator?

or make both of them thunk action creators and put saveUserToDevice() inside loginUser() then let them dispatch using their own dispatch function?

Comment: Sorry I enter a wrong action type a while ago for method 2, it should be type: SAVE_USER_TO_DEVICE

Comment: I have added Method 3 and 4. Please check which one is your recommended method.

Comment: Does it need to be dispatched twice if following the approach of making saveUserToDevice being an action? 
dispatch(saveUserToDevice(user));
 dispatch({type: SAVE_USER_TO_DEVICE, payload: saveUserToDeviceStatus});

Comment: @Kevin The correct way here is to make both of them as action creator which is the first method in my approach as it gives you more flexibility to add more logic and also update the state from within saveUserToDevice. Also because of writing it as a thunk action creator you would use this as an independent action too